# Remove first responder from a group of NSTextFields by pressing tab or clicking outside

Tags: xcode, macos, nstextfield

I'm developing an app for MacOSX in Xcode

[image]

which is a screen with a group of NSTextFields selectable and editable all of them

Every time I press tab this changes from NSTextField to NSTextField in ordered way...

Now I want to remove textfield's first responder by clicking outside of any NSTextField or when I go to last NSTextField of the NSWindowController, lets call it **descripcionBitacoraTextField**

as far as I know there's a method called

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

and I added there next code

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSTextField *textField = (NSTextField *)[aNotification object];


    if (textField == self.descripcionBitacoraTextField) {
        [[textField window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
    }
}
```

which triggers when I finish editing any textField but when I press Tab button for finishing last NSTextField, it starts focusing my first NSTextField like an endless carrousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for clicking outside:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
}
```

if you want to exit when you tab last NSTextField you can:

```
-(BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector{

    NSTextField *textField = (NSTextField *) control;

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:) && (textField == self.descripcionBitacoraTextField)) {
        [self.window makeFirstResponder:[[textView window]nextResponder]];
        return YES;
    }
    else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:)){
        [self.window makeFirstResponder:[self.contentView viewWithTag:(textField.tag +1)]];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```